# How to cut after a certain sequence of characters in python

Tags: python, split, char

I want to take a string (Example: TestExample123) and cut off the numbers after a certain set of characters (Giving output 123) but am not aware of any way I could do this. Any help would be great, but do note I am fairly new to coding and as such may not be able to do insanely advanced stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: use `your_string.split("123")[0]` to get the first part before `"123"`

Comment: yea that would work but the 123 will vary, so cannot just hard code it, but the "example" part of the string stays the same so that is what i want to be the cutoff point if that makes any sense

Comment: can you give more examples?

Comment: how will it vary? Where will you get it from?

Comment: Add several pairs of input -> expected output

Comment: given xexample# where x=any string and #=any number, it would output #. There could very well be a simple workaround i just have not thought of.

Comment: string.split("example")[1]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but definitely a good start is trying to use RegEx.

```
import re

reg = "\d"

text = "TestExample123"
text_2 = "Test123Example123"

regexed_text = re.sub(reg, "", text))
regexed_text_2 = re.sub(reg, "", text_2))
```

This gives `regexed_text = "TestExample"` and also `regexed_text_2 = "TestExample"`

`re.sub(reg, "", text)` substitutes all of the `reg` regex matching elements with empty (`""`) in the given input string variable `text`

`\d` means any numeric digit

Check out RegEx patterns for more info: [rexegg.com](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).